# Nativescript suddenly can't find a plugin when building which it found before with no issues?

Tags: angular, nativescript

I am busy with a very basic barcode scanner app.  i'm using Angular/Nativescript and i'm using the nativescript-barcodescanner plugin.  The barcode scanner plugin worked fine up to a few hours ago.  I changed some things in app.component.ts, but nothing specific to the plugin.  Now when I build my app I can see during the build process that it finds and uses the plugin but after deploying to the genymotion emulator I get the following error.  i've removed/re-installed the plugin and the android platform with no change...  Any idea what else I can try/look at?  it seems from the error message that it's looking for the plugin at app/tns_modules but I don't have a tns_modules folder in app (not sure if it moves/builds in another directory...

my error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.tns.NativeScriptApplication: com.tns.NativeScriptException: 

Error calling module function 

Error calling module function 

Error: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "nativescript-BarcodeScanner", relative to: /app/tns_modules/
    com.tns.Module.resolvePathHelper(Module.java:220)
    com.tns.Module.resolvePath(Module.java:60)
    com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Native Method)
    com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Runtime.java:244)
    com.tns.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:238)
    com.tns.NativeScriptApplication.onCreate(NativeScriptApplication.java:17)
    android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
    android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4328)
    android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:
```

my app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeScriptFormsModule } from "nativescript-angular/forms";
import { NativeScriptModule } from "nativescript-angular/platform";

import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { BarcodeScanner } from "nativescript-BarcodeScanner";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";




import { RestService } from './services/rest.service';

@NgModule({
    imports : [
    NativeScriptModule,     
    NativeScriptFormsModule, 
    HttpModule
    ],
    declarations : [
    AppComponent    
    ],
    providers : [
    RestService,
    BarcodeScanner],
    bootstrap : [AppComponent]      
})
export class AppModule {}
```

my app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { BarcodeScanner } from "nativescript-BarcodeScanner";
import { ProductModel } from './models/product';

import { RestService } from './services/rest.service';



@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    templateUrl : "./app.component.html"
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    public barcode: number;
    public textBarcode: number;
    @Input() product: ProductModel;


    public constructor(private restService: RestService, private barcodeScanner: BarcodeScanner) {

    }

    submitTextBarcode() {
        this.restService.getProduct(this.textBarcode)
    .subscribe(
    (res) => {
        this.product = new ProductModel(res.BaseURI, res.CustomError, res.ProviderName, res.RequestFormData, res.RequestURI, res.ResponseCode, res.AvgQty1, res.AvgQty2, res.AvgQty3, res.BarCode, res.Description, res.POSDescription, res.POSPrice, res.ProductCode, res.PurchCount, res.StockOnHand);    },
    (res) => {
        console.log("failure" + res);
    }
    );  
    }


    submitBarcode(barcode: number){ 
    this.restService.getProduct(barcode)
    .subscribe(
    (res) => {
        this.product = new ProductModel(res.BaseURI, res.CustomError, res.ProviderName, res.RequestFormData, res.RequestURI, res.ResponseCode, res.AvgQty1, res.AvgQty2, res.AvgQty3, res.BarCode, res.Description, res.POSDescription, res.POSPrice, res.ProductCode, res.PurchCount, res.StockOnHand);
        //console.log("returned product description: " + this.product.Description);
        //console.log(res);
    },
    (res) => {
        console.log("failure" + res);
    }
    );
    //console.log("product: " + product);

}


    public scan() {
        this.barcodeScanner.scan({
            formats : "EAN_13",
            cancelLabel : "Stop scanning",
            message : "Go scan something Use the volume buttons to turn on the flash",
            preferFrontCamera : false,
            showFlipCameraButton : false
        }).then((result) => {
            this.barcode = +result.text;
            this.submitBarcode(this.barcode);           
        }, (errorMessage) => {
            console.log("Error no scan" + errorMessage);
        });
    }

    public ngOnInit() {     

    }

}
```

Comment: Try cleaning the platforms folder and rebuilding. Or just delete platforms and then `run` to generate a new build. Might help clear this up

Comment: @Brad Martin i've done that but still no luck...

Comment: So it seems the issue is in app.module.ts:  The only differences is that I added Barcodescanner to the import list and to the providers?

Comment: try using lowercase for your imports.. it works on my side so I guess Angular-CLi is not happy wth the Upper case for "nativescript-BarcodeScanner";

Comment: Yep - what an eye by Nick :) that should fix your issue with the import complaining.

Comment: Thanks @Nick Iliev  please add that as an answer.  it's working fine now...  thanks again I struggled with this for hours:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lowercase for your imports.. it works on my side so I guess Angular-CLi is not happy wth the CamelCase in `from "nativescript-BarcodeScanner";`